# C# SqlDataAdapter with JOIN of tables from multiple databases

Tags: c#, join, connection-string, sqldataadapter

Since the sintax for define a SqlDataAdapter is:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querystring, connectionstring);
```

how can I JOIN tables from multiple databases having a single connectionstring to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your DB then it might be possible to use a DBLink.

For example for Oracle:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/managing-database-links

This joins databases together at the DB level, and allows for certain tables, views, etc. to be available for defined operations from one DB to another.

Then, from the user perspective you just connect to one DB, execute your query, which can then use tables joined from multiple DBs without even being aware.

There are however downsides including security (more complex to secure) and performance.

It may be beneficial in some cases to execute two queries on two DBs separately and then join the data in memory inside your application.
But only you can judge this, and may need to run tests to verify which is best for you.

Comment: I agree with jason.kaisersmith, the best approach is to load data in different connections and then joining them. I recommend the use of `DataSet` objects for performance.